# Understanding malloc with char pointers and strcpy

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, strcpy

I want to write a simple program and I want it to fail to understand strcpy and proper memory management but it still executes. I am trying to dynamically allocate memory (with malloc) for a string enough for only 3 (or anything less than the source) chars to be used as the destination and allocate less memory (or chars) than the string array of the source which is allocated on the stack (string of 10 chars). It copies and prints the content no matter how I define the memory allocation. what's the mistake here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *ch = NULL;
    char name[10] = "something";
    ch = (char*)malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(ch, name);
    
    printf("%s\n", name);
    free(ch);
    ch = NULL;
}
```

Comment: "I want it to fail to understand strcpy and proper memory management but it still executes"  Huh...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of writing array out of bounds is undefined. On my computer, without optimization:

```
% gcc overflow.c
% ./a.out    
something
```

and with optimization enabled

```
% gcc -O3 overflow.c
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:495,
                 from overflow.c:2:
In function ‘strcpy’,
    inlined from ‘main’ at overflow.c:10:5:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:90:10: warning: 
     ‘__builtin___memcpy_chk’ writing 10 bytes into a region of size 3
     overflows the destination [-Wstringop-overflow=]
   90 |   return __builtin___strcpy_chk (__dest, __src, __bos (__dest));
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
% ./a.out       
*** buffer overflow detected ***: terminated
[2]    240741 abort (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

The reason is that *with* optimization GCC will actually propagate the array sizes and will produce machine code equivalent to

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[10] = "something";
    char *ch = malloc(3);
    __memcpy_chk(ch, name, sizeof name, 3);
    puts(name);
    free(ch);
}
```

and [`__memcpy_chk`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/libc---memcpy-chk-1.html) **will** check the length of the destination buffer, and since it is exceeded, the program will **abort** at runtime.

Always when developing, remember to test your code **optimizations enabled too**!

Answer (score 2):

The mistake here is you're relying on [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Compiler does not throw any error for out-of-bound (or invalid) memory access, but when your program try to access an invalid memory, the behaviour is undefined.

For `strcpy()`, in case the destination buffer is not large enough to hold the content from the source, including the null-terminator, then essentially you'll be accessing memory out of bound, which is invalid, causing the undefined behaviour. It's the responsibility of the programmer to ensure the destination buffer has enough space to store the string to be copied.

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy)

> *The `strcpy()` function copies the string pointed to by `src`, including the terminating null byte (`'\0'`), to the buffer pointed to by `dest`. The strings may not overlap, and the destination string `dest` must be large enough to receive the copy.[....]*

Comment: oh I see. So this code is doing what I want and is not properly allocating memory but still executing?

Comment: @Onederfoo yes. Undefined bahaviour includes "apparently working fine"